# how to convert opencv mat image to android yuv_420_888?

Tags: android, opencv

I am using open cv android and camera x for a project in android . I am a beginner I found the code to convert yuv_420_888 to open cv mat and can do my image processing but how do I reconvert my mat image to android supported format for displaying it in camera X?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to ask how to display a Mat on a cell phone rather than in Camera X library (I have no idea how to display an image on Camera).

First, you have to convert Mat to Bitmap.

```
/**
 * Convert cv::Mat to Bitmap
 * @param mat cv::Mat to be converted in the format of CV_8UC1', 'CV_8UC3' or 'CV_8UC4'.
 * @param bitmapFormat Bitmap Format to be converted. Only support Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 or Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
 * @return Return Bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap mat2Bitmap(Mat mat, Bitmap.Config bitmapFormat) {

    if (mat == null) return null;

    if (bitmapFormat != Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 && bitmapFormat != Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) {
        bitmapFormat = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    // Create empty bitmap
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.width(), mat.height(), bitmapFormat);

    // Convert
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, result);

    return result;
}
```

Then you can display bitmap on ImageView

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

or on TextureView.

```
/**
 * A texture view to display bitmap which contains a thread looper to display bitmap continuously.
 *
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * // *** To use the drawing thread ***
 * // Get the view by ID
 * BitmapTextureView textureView = View.findViewById(R.id.view);
 *
 * // Set lambda function
 * Bitmap bitmap;
 * textureView.setDrawBitmapLambda(() -> bitmap);
 *
 * // Start thread
 * textureView.startThread();
 * }
 * </pre>
 *
 * Created by kcwong.joe@gmail.com on 4/23/2021
 **/
public class BitmapTextureView extends TextureView implements Runnable{

    public interface DrawBitmapLambda {
        public Bitmap draw();
    }

    /**
     * Set it as false to resize the image to fit the TextureView. Default as true which is to resize image which keep the image aspect ratio;
     */
    public boolean keepAspectRatio = true;

    private static final String TAG ="BitmapTextureView";

    private Thread mThread = new Thread(this, TAG);
    private volatile boolean mIsRunning = false;
    private volatile boolean mStopThread = false;
    private long mThreadDelay = 50; // in ms

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private DrawBitmapLambda mDrawBitmapLambda = null;

    // region Constructor

    public BitmapTextureView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public BitmapTextureView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BitmapTextureView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    // endregion

    /**
     * Draw bitmap on texture view
     * @param bitmap
     * @return
     */
    public boolean drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        boolean result = false;

        // Draw
        if (bitmap != null) {

            // Get canvas from surface and lock
            Canvas canvas = this.lockCanvas(null);

            // Get canvas, draw it
            if(canvas != null){

                // Resize bitmap
                bitmap = resizeBitmap(bitmap, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), keepAspectRatio);

                // Draw
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

                // unlock surface
                this.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //region Thread

    /**
     * Set the function of the looper thread.
     *
     * <pre>
     * {@code
     * Bitmap bitmap;
     * textureView.setDrawBitmapLambda(() -> bitmap);
     * }
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param drawBitmapLambda Bitmap()
     */
    public void setDrawBitmapLambda(DrawBitmapLambda drawBitmapLambda) {
        mDrawBitmapLambda = drawBitmapLambda;
    }

    /**
     * Start the looper
     * @return Return true if success
     */
    public boolean startThread() {

        boolean result = false;
        if (!isRunningThread() && mDrawBitmapLambda != null) {
            mThread.start();
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Stop the looper
     */
    public void stopThread() {
        mStopThread = true;
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the Looper is running.
     * @return Return true if the Looper is running.
     */
    public boolean isRunningThread() {
        return mIsRunning;
    }

    /**
     * Run function. Don't call run() to start the thread. Use startThread() instead.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mStopThread = false;
        mIsRunning = true;
        while (!mStopThread) {

            // Run lambda
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (mDrawBitmapLambda != null) {
                bitmap = mDrawBitmapLambda.draw();
            }

            // Draw
            if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.sameAs(mBitmap)) {
                boolean result = drawBitmap(bitmap);
                if (result) mBitmap = bitmap;
            }

            // Wait ms
            try {
                Thread.sleep(mThreadDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // endregion

    /**
     * Resize bitmap. The input bitmap will be recycled to reduce the memory.
     * @param bitmap Bitmap to be resized
     * @param resizedWidth Resized width
     * @param resizedHeight  Resized height
     * @param fixAspectRatio Resize image which keep the original image aspect ratio? If true, the size of resized bitmap may be smaller than resizedWidth and resizedHeight.
     * @return Return the resized bitmap.
     */
    private static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int resizedWidth, int resizedHeight, boolean fixAspectRatio) {

        // Get size
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        // Calculate scale
        float scaleWidth = ((float) resizedWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) resizedHeight) / height;
        if (fixAspectRatio) {
            if (scaleWidth != scaleHeight) {
                float scale = Math.min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                scaleWidth = scale;
                scaleHeight = scale;
            }
        }

        // Create the transform matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // Resize
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        // Recycle
        bitmap.recycle();

        // Return
        return result;
    }
}
```